# Does the following equation system have an analytical solution?

Tags: systems-of-equations

I feel something like this must have been asked before, but can't really find it. Context below.

$\sum_{j=0}^{M}\left[(e^{-\sqrt{(x-x_{j})^2+(y-y_{j})^2+(z-z_{j})^2}}-e^{-r_{j}}) \frac{-(x-x_{j})}{\sqrt{(x-x_{j})^2+(y-y_{j})^2+(z-z_{j})^2}} \right]=0$

$\sum_{j=0}^{M}\left[(e^{-\sqrt{(x-x_{j})^2+(y-y_{j})^2+(z-z_{j})^2}}-e^{-r_{j}}) \frac{-(y-y_{j})}{\sqrt{(x-x_{j})^2+(y-y_{j})^2+(z-z_{j})^2}} \right]=0$

$\sum_{j=0}^{M}\left[(e^{-\sqrt{(x-x_{j})^2+(y-y_{j})^2+(z-z_{j})^2}}-e^{-r_{j}}) \frac{-(z-z_{j})}{\sqrt{(x-x_{j})^2+(y-y_{j})^2+(z-z_{j})^2}} \right]=0$

where $x_{j}$, $y_{j}$ , $z_{j}$ and $r_{j}$ are constants for $j=0$ to $j=M$

**CONTEXT**

I have point $(x,y,z)$ and a set of points $(x_{j},y_{j},z_{j})$ for $j=0$ to $j=M$. That set of points move on space almost independently of each other, and I want to find the coordinates of a new point $(x,y,z)$ that mimicks the distances to each point $(x_{j},y_{j},z_{j})$ with the minimum possible error. Also, if a point $(x_{j},y_{j},z_{j})$ is originally closer to $(x,y,z)$, the error with respect to this point should be lower.

For this, I have defined the following function:

$F=\sum_{j=0}^{M}\left[(e^{-r_{j}}-e^{-r_{j_{0}}})^{2}\right]$

where $r_{j}$ are constants and $r_{j}=\sqrt{(x-x_{j})^{2}+(y-y_{j})^{2}+(z-z_{j})^{2}}$

To find the minimum values of x, y and z, I calculated the partial derivatives of F with respect to x, y and z and ended up with the displayed system of equations.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Let's consider most simple non-trivial case. $M=1$, 1D. Then equation becomes $e^{-|x-x_0|}+e^{-|x-x_1|}=e^{-r_0}+e^{-r_1}$. This equation can be solved analytically. Increasing $M$ does not change this fact, but increases number of cases substantially, so the answer will severely depend on relations between $x_i$ and $r_i$. I don't understand what can be profit from such answer as it cannot be use for calculations. Increasing dimensionality of problem makes this problem more complex, and I believe there is no reason to solve it in general form.